# scalaz MVar take method blocks infinitely

Tags: concurrency, scalaz

I'm new to scalaz and I want to explore the usage of MVar. So I made a little script this:

```
object MVarThingy {

  val haha = newEmptyMVar[Int]

  def forkIO(f: => IO[Unit])(implicit s: Strategy): IO[Unit] = IO {
    s(f.unsafePerformIO)
  }

  def writeDelay(v: MVar[Int]): IO[Unit] = for {
    _ <- IO(println("wait to put value to haha"))
    _ <- IO(Thread.sleep(5000))
    _ <- IO(println("now put value to haha"))
    _ <- v.put(42)
  } yield ()

  def writeNow(v: MVar[Int]): IO[Unit] = v.put(24)

  def takeHaha: IO[Int] = for {
    v <- haha
    _ <- IO(println("try to get haha.."))
    a <- v.take
  } yield a

  def run(): Unit = {
    val blah = for {
      mvar <- haha
      _ <- forkIO(writeDelay(mvar))
      a <- takeHaha
    } yield a

    println("value in mvar is: " + blah.unsafePerformIO)
  }
}
```

if I run `MVarThingy.run`, it will block infinitely.

However If I change `takeHaha` and `run` to

```
  def takeHaha(v: MVar[Int]): IO[Int] = for {
    _ <- IO(println("try to get haha.."))
    a <- v.take
  } yield a

  def run(): Unit = {
    val blah = for {
      mvar <- haha
      _ <- forkIO(writeDelay(mvar))
      a <- takeHaha(mvar)
    } yield a

    println("value in mvar is: " + blah.unsafePerformIO)
  }
```

then everything works as I expected, after value is put, value will be taken and program will terminate normally.

Could you please explain me why will there be such difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out that `newEmptyMVar[A]` will produce `IO[MVar[A]]`, and `IO[A]` is lazy.

In first case I get two different `MVar`.